# redmine write test for all plugins together

Tags: testing, plugins, redmine

I've written a "Test plugin", i could run every now and then on my Redmine app, without being have to run all the test folder. the problem is it only refers to the core and ignores the "plugins" folder.

how can make sure that while running the test suite I've build it will include all the plugins in the "plugins" folder?

Answer (score 1):

You could run all tests with these 2 commands:

```
# Redmine core tests    
bundle exec rake test
# Plugins tests
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:test
```

Comment: Thank's, but as I said- my problem is not running all the tests (Plugins or Core). My problem is I've made a test suit for all the app (Plugins and Core) AS ONE OF MY PLUGINS- meaning I have a plugin called-"Redmine test suit".  but when i run it in only "sees" the core and not the plugins.